# Task Scheduler Win 10 - Run whether user is logged on or not

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I am using Task Scheduler to run 2 tasks everyday with security options is 'Run whether user is logged on or not' but one of them did not work.

Task1:
Action: Start a program
Program/script: `D:\myfolder\deletecsv.bat`
Add arguments: blank
Start in: blank
Code in `deletecsv.bat`:

```
@echo off
d:
cd D:\myfolder
del *.csv
```

Task2:
Action: Start a program
Program/script: `D:\myfolder\runexcel.bat`
Add arguments: blank
Start in: blank
Code in `runexcel.bat`:

```
@echo off
start Excel.exe "D:\myfolder\myexcel.xlsb"
```

Task1 works well, but Task2 doesn't.
Besides, when I created these tasks in 'Create basic task' with 'Run only when user is logged on', they work well.

My user has been added to the Administrator Group, 'Log on as a batch job' , 'Log on as a service'.

Comment: In the Task Scheduler, what does it say in the "Last Run Time" and "Last Run Result" columns? Is it the second task that didn't run? That may be because you need a logged in user to run GUI-based applications.

Comment: have you tried any methods to run things as a service?

Answer (score 1):

Excel can only run in the context of a logged-in interactive user session.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234615/excel-com-automation-via-interactive-user-stops-working-when-user-logs-off/4241070#4241070